# why code is different on my local and on chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

As the picture shows: I noticed my code is slightly different on Chrome, why is this happen? what's the purpose to chrome?
[image]

Comment: caching? tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrow method that you have used is ES6 syntax. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions.
It binds the `this` context on your function.

Most likely you have a complier which converts the ES6 code you write into syntax that can be understood by the browser. So anywhere you have ES6 Syntax written will get converted to browser compatible Javascript so that it can run on the Browser.

You can use the `ES6 to Browser compatible code` converter here to understand how es6 code is converted.
https://babeljs.io/

Here is an example of what is happening in you case

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear your cache:

CTRL+SHIFT+DELETE then select checkbox with cache and click on the button

or

You should have opened developer tool and do right click on the reload icon and click "Empty cache and hard reload"